# Getting all documents in Elastic Search Shard

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to get all documents in a shard.

This query returns all the documents that I have in my elasticsearch cluster rather than just the documents in the shard with id: `254b2796-9be4-4704-b756-6fe2e3e80f36`

```
GET /mortgages/_search?routing=254b2796-9be4-4704-b756-6fe2e3e80f36
```

On the other hand, this query returns just the documents in the shard `254b2796-9be4-4704-b756-6fe2e3e80f36`

```
GET /mortgages/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_routing": [ "254b2796-9be4-4704-b756-6fe2e3e80f36" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

From the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html), it seems that both queries should be valid. Why is the first query not working, but the second query is?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the first query HTTP method from `GET` to `POST`, there are a few ES API issues, where it doesn't work with `GET` method with request param instead request body in `GET` request works.

Comment: The result of both the queries was exactly the same with GET and POST

Comment: @AshishAgarwal, strange let me see if I can find something from source code

Comment: @AshishAgarwal, sorry I was not able to spend much time on this, just wanted to know if you found something useful so that I can work on it